# C++11 app that uses dispatch_apply not working under Mac OS Sierra

Tags: c++11, grand-central-dispatch, macos-sierra

I had a completely functioning codebase written in C++11 that used Grand Central Dispatch parallel processing, specifically *dispatch_apply* to do the basic parallel for loop for some trivial game calculations.

Since upgrading to Sierra, this code still runs, but each block is run in serial -- the *cout* statement shows that they are being executed in serial order, and CPU usage graph shows no parallel working on.

Queue is defined as:

```
workQueue = dispatch_queue_create("workQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

And the relevant program code is:

```
            case Concurrency::Parallel: {
                    dispatch_apply(stateMap.size(), workQueue, ^(size_t stateIndex) {
                        string thisCode = stateCodes[stateIndex];
                        long thisCount = stateCounts[stateIndex];

                        GameResult sliceResult = playStateOfCode(thisCode, thisCount);
                        results[stateIndex] = sliceResult;

                        if ((stateIndex + 1) % updatePeriod == 0) {
                            cout << stateIndex << endl;
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
```

I strongly suspect that this either a bug, but if this is GCD forcing me to use new C++ methods for this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is a bug in Sierra or not. But it seems to work if you explicitly associate a global concurrent queue as target:

```
dispatch_queue_t target =
        dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0);
dispatch_queue_t workQueue = 
        dispatch_queue_create_with_target("workQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT, target);
//                            ^~~~~~~~~~~                                         ^~~~~~
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem.  Now, I just need to find a way to make this work using Swift 3's *DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations:)* method, which still seems to have that bug.  But I appreciate the workaround!

Comment: I don't suppose you'd know enough about Swift 3 to suggest how to leverage a similar workaround for the Swift concurrency method as demonstrated in

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843007/swift-app-using-dispatchqueue-concurrentperformiterations-no-longer-runs-conc

Thanks for your time either way though, definitely appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>

void load_problem(const std::string, std::vector<std::pair<double,double>>&);

int main() {
    // n-factor polynomial - test against a given problem provided as a set of space delimited x y values in 2d.txt
    std::vector<std::pair<double,double>> problem;
    std::vector<double> test = {14.1333177226503,-0.0368874860476915,
        0.0909424058436257,2.19080982673558,1.24632025036125,0.0444549880462031,
        1.06824631867947,0.551482840616757, 1.04948148731933};
    load_problem("weird.txt",problem); //a list of space delimited doubles representing x, y.
    
    size_t a_count = test.size();
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    __block double diffs = 0.0; //sum of all values..
    dispatch_apply(problem.size(), queue, ^(size_t i) {
        double g = 0;
        for (size_t j=0; j < a_count - 1; j++) {
            g += test[j]*pow(problem[i].first,a_count - j - 1);
        }
        g += test[a_count - 1];
        diffs += pow(g - problem[i].second,2);
    });
    double delta = 1/(1+sqrt(diffs));
    std::cout << "test: fit delta: " << delta << std::endl;
}

void load_problem(const std::string file, std::vector<std::pair<double,double>>& repo) {
    repo.clear();
    std::ifstream ifs(file);
    if (ifs.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        while(getline(ifs, line)) {
            double x= std::nan("");
            double y= std::nan("");
            std::istringstream istr(line);
            istr >> std::skipws >> x >> y;
            if (!isnan(x) && !isnan(y)) {
                repo.push_back({x, y});
            };
        }
        ifs.close();
    }
}
```