# Swift app using DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations:) no longer runs concurrently under Mac OS Sierra

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, macos-sierra

In testing my code under Sierra, I found that the methods that previously handled concurrent queues were no longer working.

In analyzing the error in my C++ codebase, one of the users suggested a workaround that involved explicitly naming a target for the queue declaration (see this post: [C++11 app that uses dispatch_apply not working under Mac OS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836134/c11-app-that-uses-dispatch-apply-not-working-under-mac-os-sierra/39837486) ) that seems to have solved the problem.

In Swift 3, the following code would be used to execute a closure concurrently, but it is exhibiting a similar but to the C++ example in the above post:

```
import Foundation
import GameKit

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 1000) { index in
    let pauseTime = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 5)
    sleep(UInt32(pauseTime))
    print(index)
}
```

... however, when I execute it, it runs each block serially and the indices are output in numeric order.

Anyone know how I might leverage the workaround recommended in that post to solve my "concurrent for" dispatch issues in Swift?

Comment: Do you call `concurrentPerform()` on the main thread?

Comment: Unsure.  What you see there is literally the entire source code.  As in, I created a Swift console application, and that's the body of my Program.swift file.  Is it default for the DispatchQueue class to run on the main thread?

Comment: It should be called on a non-main thread. I haven't found any documentation for it, but I have well-tested code that works as I would expect. https://github.com/duemunk/Async/blob/master/Source/Async.swift#L538-L540

Comment: I just tried your code from the main thread and it works as you expected. It does not print index in numeric order.

Answer (score 2):

Building on duemunk's comment, here is how I apply a function `performFunction` in parallel on a background queue:

```
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue", qos: .userInteractive, attributes: .concurrent)
    queue.async {
        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: iterations) {
            index in
            performOperation(index)
        }
    }
```