# fast locking in a parallel concurrentPerform swift loop

Tags: swift, multithreading

I tried many different code to have a parallel loop faster than a sequential one.
My latest attempt :

```
startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
var totaliter = 0
for x in stride(from: -2.0, to: 2.0, by: delta) {
    for y in stride(from: -2.0, to: 2.0, by: delta) {
        let cx : Double = x
        let cy : Double = y
        var zx : Double = 0.0
        var zy : Double = 0.0
        var iteration : Int = 0
        while (zx * zx + zy * zy < 4.0 && iteration < maxIter) {
            let tmp = zx * zx - zy * zy + cx
            zy = 2.0 * zx * zy + cy
            zx = tmp
            iteration += 1
            totaliter += 1
        }
    }
}
print(totaliter)
print("\tTime : \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime)")
```

this sequential code take 4s.

The following using swift-atomic code take 29s :

```
startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
let atomicInc = ManagedAtomic<UInt32>(0)

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: Int(4/delta)) { (xIter) in
    for y in stride(from: -2.0, to: 2.0, by: delta) {
        let x = -2.0 + (Double(xIter) * delta)
        let cx : Double = x
        let cy : Double = y
        var zx : Double = 0.0
        var zy : Double = 0.0
        var iteration : Int = 0
        while (zx * zx + zy * zy < 4.0 && iteration < maxIter) {
            let tmp = zx * zx - zy * zy + cx
            zy = 2.0 * zx * zy + cy
            zx = tmp
            iteration += 1
            atomicInc.wrappingIncrement(ordering: AtomicUpdateOrdering.relaxed)
        }
    }
}
print("\n\tMeaningless number (race condition) : ",atomicInc.load(ordering: .relaxed))
print("\tTime : \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime)")
```

Replacing the atomicInc.wrappingIncrement by a NSLock lock/unlock take forever, I never had the patience to let it finish. my guess is around 10mn and the cpu is 80% busy on "system" load (as opposed to user load)

I simply can't find a way to have a parallel loop that is faster than the sequential version. All my attempts either failed or had a race condition.

For reference, my previous attempt with a different computation was like this (and, yes, the sequential version was faster than the swift-atomic or the NSLock version, I assumed that drand48 was the culprit, but it seems I was wrong)

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 100) { (_) in
    for _ in 1...iteration / 100 {
        let rand_x : Float = Float(drand48())
        let rand_y : Float = Float(drand48())
        let origin_dist : Float = rand_x * rand_x + rand_y * rand_y
        if (origin_dist <= 1) {
            atomicinside.wrappingIncrement(ordering: AtomicUpdateOrdering.relaxed)
        }
    }
}
```

**How would you do a parallel loop that require updating a non-thread-local variable ?** Anything will do as long as it's fast. I'm using concurrentPerform because I don't know any better, but I'm open to suggestions.

fun fact : the parallel version is slower while using 4~8x more CPU.

Comment: For reference : after execution, totaliter (and atomicInc) = 1239370825. So that would mean 1.2B lock.
Without lock the parallel loop take around 1s, and an incorrect result because of the race condition on the += 1

Comment: can you try executing the concurrentPerform in background queue. Like mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40401001/4637057

Comment: I'll give it a try but I'm not sure how any of this will solve anything.

Comment: yep, just tested, not solving anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the locking increment out of the inner loop and do a locking
totaliter += iteration

Comment: the code I provided was just a dummy sample to illustrate the problem. anyway, I gave up on swift since then.