# How do you use c++17 parallel standard library algorithms on mac?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, parallel-processing, c++17

I want to use parallel sort from c++17's standard library in my cmake project (it's cross platform and works great on Linux and MSYS2) but [Apple Clang's libc++ has not implemented it yet, while gnu's libstdc++ has](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). How do you use gnu's implementation of c++17's libraries in a cmake project on mac?

Comment: If a compiler doesn't support some feature, then CMake cannot help it with that. Not sure what do you want from us...

Comment: Would it be possible to use GNU's standard library, maybe using `-stdlib=libstdc++`?

Comment: CMake may be relevant just because it is used to configure the compiler and libs, and it may have features I'm not aware of that could help. `-stdlib=libstdc++` doesn't seem to make a difference. On systems where it does work, the parallel libraries use `include <execution>`. On mac, this results in `fatal error: 'execution' file not found`.

Comment: Using `glocate -r "/execution$"`, I found an execution header at `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1/include/c++/9.2.0/execution` so I added that include directory, but that header includes other missing files like `#include <bits/c++config.h>`. Is the solution to brew install some libraries and add the appropriate include/link flags? I'm looking for a brew package for that but can't find it.

Comment: Do you want to use `gcc` compiler instead of `clang`? If so, just pass appropriate `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` option to CMake. Or set `CXX` environment variable. See e.g that question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22619145/3440745.

Comment: If libstdc++ only works with the gnu compiler, then yes. gcc links to clang so I downloaded and built gcc from source (which comes with libstdc++-v3). I set the Cmake compiler options and it finds the new g++ compiler. I added -I/path/to/new/gcc/include to the compile flags and added -L/path/to/new/gcc/lib to the link flags. It compiles, but the linker now gives an error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" relating to the fmt library. I'll have to fiddle around a bit more to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to build gcc from source and use that compiler and the libraries that come with it. It also needs to be static linked with `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`. I also had trouble with the fmt library after switching to the gnu standard library, but resolved that by using the header-only version of fmt.

[Here's](https://github.com/dvhar/csvquery/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) the CMakeLists.txt file with the complete details.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to parallelise on a Mac is to follow the advice given by Apple - use dispatch calls.

I posted an example at [C++11 app that uses dispatch_apply not working under Mac OS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836134/)

This uses dispatch_apply - pretty much a drop-in for a for-to loop.